# Datagrid changes updating many properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a Datagrid bound to an ObservableCollection in a Logbook class.  Also in the Logbook class I have numerous other properties which basically account for different times that need to be added up.

The problem I'm having is I have no way of notifying the properties to update when something is added or removed from the Datagrid because I have CanUserAddRows set to true.

Is there a way to set in XAML to update these properties or should I inherit from ObservableCollection and override the methods and add my own properties with notifications?

## LogbookEntry.cs

```
public class LogbookEntry {
  public decimal TotalTime { get; set; }
  public decimal SoloTime { get; set; }
  public decimal PICTime { get; set; }
}
```

## Logbook.cs

```
public class Logbook {
  public ObservableCollection<LogbookEntry> Entries { get; private set; }

  public decimal TotalTime { get; private set; }   // THESE ALL NEED TO BE ADDED
  public decimal SoloTime { get; private set; }    // UP IN THE SAME COLUMN FROM
  public decimal PICTime { get; private set; }     // ALL ENTRIES
}
```

Right now the Datagrid just lists TotalTime, SoloTime, and PICTime columns as 0, because I have no way to update them when stuff gets added to Entries.  I'm thinking maybe:

## Logbook.cs

```
public class Logbook : ObservableCollection<LogbookEntry> {
  public decimal TotalTime { get; private set; }   
  public decimal SoloTime { get; private set; }    
  public decimal PICTime { get; private set; }

  public override Add(...) {
    base.Add(...);
    TotalTime += logbookEntry.TotalTime;
    OnPropertyChanged(TotalTime);

    SoloTime += logbookEntry.SoloTime;
    OnPropertyChanged(SoloTime);

    PICTime += logbookEntry.PICTime;
    OnPropertyChanged(PICTime);
  }
}
```

Unless there's any way for me to do this from XAML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `TotalTime`, `SoloTime`, `PICTime` properties `OneWay` bound values (no setter) and implement the getter as a LINQ call to `Sum()` the values from `Entries` collection.

Listen for `Entries.CollectionChanged` event and when adding the items to `Entries`, listen to each item's `PropertyChanged` event (if it doesn't have one, implement it). Then when either of those events are received, raise a `PropertyChanged` event for the relevant `Logbook` property (or all, in the case of a new `LogbookEntry` object added/removed).

This way, when anything changes in your `ViewModel`, you can automatically notify the UI that something has changed and the UI will update itself by calling the appropriate getter property.

Comment: Thanks for this! To make it more concrete, can you provide a few lines of code?  Thanks again!